# How do I undo an action in the review queue?

Tags: support

I think I just accidentally voted to delete a first answer at: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/15237/120 in the review queue.

Is there any way I can undo this action or is this something only a moderator can fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite sure you cannot delete an answer just by yourself. Other users get the change to review it as well - so do not worry.

The answer is still online and has not been deleted.